# how to do chain buttons for infinite with css3 animation?

Tags: css, animation

am trying to add buttons one by one with micro seconds gap around 10 buttons and then repeat it for infinite times with css3 animation.am not getting any idea to do this.

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

again repeat it for every 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Css3 animation can't do that, it can only animate the properties of DOM elements, and not their content.